Understanding complexified Levi-Civita connection in complex geometry
Proposition $3.18$ From this note we have,

Let $(X,J,g)$ be a Hermitian manifold. If we denote the complexified Levi-Civita connection by $\nabla$. $\nabla$ is characterized as the only connection on $T^{\mathbb R}X$ that is both torsion free and compatible with $g$. Then by definition we can assume, $$\nabla_{\partial_i}\partial_j=\Gamma^k_{ij}\partial_k+\Gamma^{\bar k}_{ij}\partial_{\bar k}\tag1$$
Since $\nabla$ is a real operator, we also have,
$$\nabla_{\partial_{\bar i}}\partial_{\bar j}=\overline{\Gamma^k_{ij}}\partial_{\bar k}+\overline{\Gamma^{\bar k}_{ij}}\partial_{k},\nabla_{\partial_{i}}\partial_{\bar j}=\overline{\Gamma^k_{\bar ij}}\partial_{\bar k}+\overline{\Gamma^{\bar k}_{\bar ij}}\partial_{k}\tag2$$
Then using the torsion free and metric compatibility condition we have $\Gamma^k_{ij}=\Gamma^k_{ji}=\Gamma^{\bar k}_{ij}=\Gamma^{\bar k}_{ji}$ and $\Gamma^{\bar k}_{ij}=\Gamma^{\bar k}_{\bar ij}=\Gamma^{k}_{\bar ij}=0$ resp.

$(1)$ make sense, as we decompose everything into holomorphic and anti-holomorphic coordinates. But $(2)$ doesn't make sense to me. Why we need the complex conjugate of Christoffel symbols here? what's the complex conjugates of the Christoffel symbols? And how to determine $\nabla_{\partial_{\bar i}}\partial_j=$? As it wasn't explicitly mentioned but I guess it should be $\nabla_{\partial_{\bar i}}\partial_j\stackrel{?}{=}\overline{\Gamma^k_{i\bar j}}\partial_{\bar k}+\overline{\Gamma^{\bar k}_{i\bar j}}\partial_{k}$ (without knowing why it should look like this! As I have a doubt about the \bar used in the formulas like I guess it should be $\nabla_{\partial_{\bar i}}\partial_{j}$ in $(2)$).
On section $8.4$, Geometry, Topology and Physics by Nakahara define covariant derivative differently,

Let (M, g) be a Hermitian manifold. We define a connection which is compatible with the complex structure. $$\nabla_\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial z^\nu}=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial z^\lambda}\equiv\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda, \quad\nabla_{\bar \mu} \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z^\nu}=\Gamma^{\bar \lambda}_{\bar\mu\bar\nu}(z)\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z^\lambda}\equiv\Gamma^{\bar \lambda}_{\bar\mu\bar\nu}\partial_{\bar\lambda}\tag3$$

Why isn't decomposition considered here? As @TedShifrin mention in the comment, $\frac{\partial}{\partial z^\nu}$ are holomorphic sections of the tangent bundle, their covariant derivatives are of type $(1,0)$ only. That's why $\nabla_\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial z^\nu}=\Gamma^\lambda_{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda$ make sense.
The only thing which still confuse me is $(2)$. Actually, I want to know, how to locally determine this connection intuitively. It will be a great help if anyone give me any reference/resource where I can have the motivation/derivation. TIA

What is so strange about taking the complex conjugate of Christoffel symbols? They are complex-valued functions. In the second case, “compatible with the complex structure” means a connection on the holomorphic tangent bundle.

I mean in $(2)$ why we need the complex conjugate of Christoffel symbols? @TedShifrin

A connection $\nabla$ on a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ over a complex manifold $X$ is said to be compatible with complex structure if $\nabla^{0,1} = \bar\partial_E$. I couldn't see the relation of this definition with $(3)$ (not decompose like $(1)$)? @TedShifrin

Yes, precisely. So $\nabla^{(0,1)}s = 0$ for any holomorphic section $s$.  Since $\partial/\partial z^\nu$ are holomorphic sections of the tangent bundle, their covariant derivatives are of type $(1,0)$ only.

Thanks, it makes sense to me now @TedShifrin Can you say why we need the complex conjugate of Christoffel symbols in $(2)$? That's the last question which is still not clear to me. And thanks again

I still didn't manage any information regarding this question. Also, bounty didn't draw enough attention. Can you suggest any resource where I can at least have some information about this? @TedShifrin It will be a great help.

The note explains it just fine. Note that you omitted part of their definition. Write down what it means for the operator to be real.

I understand the rest of the part where the author uses Kahler stuff and show that it is Chern connection, that's why remove the Kahler things and mention only the Hermitian part. Aha, I forgot to mention $\nabla$ is a real operator. A real structure on a complex vector space $V$ is an antilinear involution $\sigma :V\to V$ ($\sigma^2=id_V$, $\sigma(\lambda x)=\bar\lambda \sigma(x)$). I guess the same definition apply here also(?). But still I guess I didn't get how it implies $(2)$, @TedShifrin

If $T$ is a real operator on the complex vector space, then $T(\bar v) = \overline{T(v)}$. You still omitted part of his definition in (1).

I suggest working out all of the details for $\dim X = 1$, first using real coordinates $(x,y)$ and coordinate vector fields $\partial_x, \partial_y$ and then converting the equations to use the complex coordinates $z = x+iy,\ \bar{z}=x-iy$ and coordinate vector fields $\partial_z, \partial_{\bar{z}}$. When I learned this stuff, I found it veru helpful to learn it all first for Riemann surfaces before tackling higher dimensional cases.

(1) Sorry for late response, as I am going through my year final exam. Thank you for your suggestion. If I understand your comment, $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z}} \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\stackrel{?}{=}\nabla_{\frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)}\frac12\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)=\frac12\left[\frac12(-i)\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\frac12(i)\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right]$ and use connection coefficient?

(2) But I didn't find it similar with $(2)$, @Deane If you don't mind then can you enlighten me? And thanks for your response.

I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution to my question. I even spent a bounty on it. It would be really helpful if you could show me how to solve it when $\dim X=1$, @Deane . I'd like to understand the approach and try extending it to higher dimensions on my own.
